# How to wrap ArcEngine Sketch Control?

Tags: arcgis-engine

I've created a small API to wrap ArcEngine controls so I can customize them (my own toolbars, my icons, etc) and I'm having problem with the ControlsEditingSketchToolClass control.

I basically have a command pool that gets initialized against a AxMapControl and if it's a tool and set the tool to be the current map tool. If it's a command i just execute it.

Looks like it works fine for other commands and tools (pan, zoom, select all, unselect, select features) but not for Sketch Control. When I try to activate it, it is always disabled.

According to ESRI docs:

> The CLSID of this command is: {13B234E8-3B30-49CA-9967-4C76F7231AD6}.
>
> This command works with the ToolbarControl, PageLayoutControl and
>   MapControl.
>
> If the ArcGIS Engine application using this command is initialized
>   with an ArcGIS Engine Runtime license or an ArcView license, this
>   command can be used to edit shapefiles and personal geodatabases.
>
> If the ArcGIS Engine application using this command is initialized
>   with an ArcGIS Engine GeoDatabase Editing license, or ArcEditor or
>   ArcInfo, this command can be used to edit data within an enterprise
>   geodatabase.

The edit session is in place and it's using my map and my workspace for sure!

In my command pool I'm also sure that I call the OnCreate method using ICommandPoolEdit.CallOnCreate()

Here's the method I use for activating the tool/command:

```
    public virtual void Activate(IExecutionContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(context != null);

        if (Checker != null)
            if (!Checker.HasPermission(context, this))
                throw new NotAllowedException("This command cannot be execute using this execution context");

        if (TargetType == typeof(AxMapControl))
        {
            var map = (AxMapControl)_registry.Hook;

            if (_innerCommand is ITool && _innerCommand.Enabled)
            // this tool is ALWAYS DISABLED
            {
                map.CurrentTool = ((ITool)_innerCommand);
                return;
            }

            if (_innerCommand is ICommand && _innerCommand.Enabled)
            {
                _innerCommand.OnClick();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (TargetType == typeof(AxPageLayoutControl))
        {
            var map = (AxPageLayoutControl)_registry.Hook;

            if (_innerCommand is ITool && _innerCommand.Enabled)
            {
                map.CurrentTool = ((ITool)_innerCommand);
                return;
            }

            if (_innerCommand is ICommand && _innerCommand.Enabled)
            {
                _innerCommand.OnClick();
                return;
            }
        }

        _stats.SessionUsageCount++;
    }
```

Any tips?

Comment: Have you set a target layer on the editor (IEngineEditLayers)? Have you set a current task on the editor (IEngineEditor)?

Comment: Yes I had both. I managed to figure this one out. I need to pass along to my Hook the actual IMapDefault interface instead of AxMapControl.